# Specifying user and password when doing restoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot AWS SDK call

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

I am trying to use the AWS PHP SDK call restoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot

I don't see any parameters allowing me to enter a master user name and a master password. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you'd need to run `modify-db-instance` to change the master password after restoring the DB